# How to get woocommerce inventory status

Tags: functions, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

In a woocommerce theme, Im trying to show a warning when product is out of stock. Something like this:

```
<?php if ('this_product_is_out_of_stock'): ?>
    <p>This product is out of stock. It can be purchased by custom made order.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a function to say 'this_product_is_out_of_stock' or some other way to achieve it?

I was searching woocommerce api docs unsuccesfully: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions about the inner workings of third party plugins are better asked at their author's forum, in this case: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like this

```
    global $product;
    if ( ! $product->managing_stock() && ! $product->is_in_stock() )
    echo '<p>This product is out of stock. It can be purchased by custom made order.</p>';
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. I tried it again and it works (I had a syntax error in my previous try). Thank you very much.

Comment: this works, but why `! $product->managing_stock()`..? only show out of stock, if stock managment is disabled..? (plus the other rule, but.. why?) i now left this part out and it works like intended ❤️